# How to filter data of CASE WHEN statement using where condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, ssms-2012

After allies CASE WHEN condition as column can we filter that column?

Example;

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Number like '20%' THEN 'X'
   WHEN Number like '15%' or  Number like '16%'  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z'
   END Operation
   ,*
FROM 
TableA
where Operation like 'X'
```

I called CASE WHEN condition as 'Operation' and now I want to see only the Operation 'X' in the Operation column.

Is there a way to filter CASE WHEN condition with where clause in SSMS 2012?

Comment: Why not just directly `WHERE Number LIKE '20%'`? and since you filter the result set you don't need for `CASE` expression, just `'X' AS Operation`

Comment: I actually have multiple CASE WHEN statements but yeah using Number as a filter condition also works and simple. Thanks @Sami

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your query up as a *derived table*, then you can put the new column in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select * 
from
(
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN Number like '20%' THEN 'X'
       WHEN Number like '15%' or [Item Number] like '16%'  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z'
       END Operation
       ,*
    FROM 
    TableA
) dt
where Operation like 'X'
```

Comment: Simply `Operation = 'X'`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT A.*, AA.*
FROM TableA AS A CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (CASE WHEN Number like '20%'  
                    THEN 'X'
                    WHEN (Number like '15%' OR [Item Number] like '16%')  
                    THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z'
               END ) 
     ) AA(Operation)
WHERE AA.Operation = 'X';
```

This would helpful if you have a other filters as well. However only `WHERE Number LIKE '20%'` is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

With the condition that you want to apply, your statement is equivalent to:

```
SELECT 'X' AS Operation, *
FROM 
TableA
where Number like '20%'
```

Comment: Aaaah nice one forpas :D

Answer (score 1):

Just another options

Using CTE

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
      CASE WHEN Number like '20%' THEN 'X'
     WHEN Number like '15%' or  Number like '16%'  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z'
     END Operation
     ,*
  FROM 
  TableA
)
SELECT *
FROM CTR
WHERE Operation = 'X';
```

Using CASE expression

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Number like '20%' THEN 'X'
   WHEN Number like '15%' or  Number like '16%'  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z'
   END Operation
   ,*
FROM 
TableA
WHERE CASE WHEN Number like '20%' THEN 'X'
           WHEN Number like '15%' or  Number like '16%'  THEN 'Y' 
           ELSE 'Z'
      END = 'X';
```

---

Now, let's see [your last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220715/how-to-filter-data-of-case-when-statement-using-where-condition/54221031#comment95267372_54220715)

> I actually have multiple CASE WHEN statements but yeah using Number as a filter condition also works and simple.

Alright, you don't need a `CASE` expression for the `Number` column

```
SELECT 'X' Operation,
       --Another CASE here if needed
       ,*
FROM 
TableA
WHERE Number like '20%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You must repeat the `CASE` expression in the WHERE clause, or nest this inside another SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use a column alias  in where  ondition  .. if you need  you could use having (that work on the result values  or subquery )

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Number like '20%' THEN 'X'
   WHEN Number like '15%' or  Number like '16%'  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z'
   END Operation
   ,*
FROM  TableA
HAVING Operation like 'X'
```

subquery and where

```
select operation from (

  SELECT 
      CASE WHEN Number like '20%' THEN 'X'
     WHEN Number like '15%' or  Number like '16%'  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z'
     END Operation
     ,*
  FROM  TableA

  ) t 
  where operation = 'X'
```

otherwise you should reuse the same code for case  in where clause

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Number like '20%' THEN 'X'
   WHEN Number like '15%' or  Number like '16%'  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z'
   END Operation
   ,*
FROM  TableA
 WHERE  CASE WHEN Number like '20%' THEN 'X'
   WHEN Number like '15%' or  Number like '16%'  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z'
   END like 'X'
```